# Error loading design while coding a CRC implementation in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

While all the code is perfectly compiled by ModelSim, I can't simulate it because of "Error loading design"

This is for a CRC encode and decode using a Linear Feedback Shift Register that uses D-FlipFlop as components. So the project is actually composed by the CRC box that contains the LFSR made by DFF.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity CRC is
    generic (
        NBit    : positive := 64;
        poly    : positive := 8
        );
    port(
        clk :in     std_logic;
        reset   :in     std_logic;
        md  :in std_logic; --1 per sender, 0 per receiver
        input   :in     std_logic_vector(Nbit-1 downto 0);
        dout_s  :out    std_logic_vector(Nbit-1 downto 0);
        dout_r  :out    std_logic_vector(Nbit-poly-1 downto 0)
        );
    end CRC;

architecture rtl of CRC is

    component LFSR
        generic (N  : positive := 8);
        port(
            clk :in     std_logic;
            reset   :in     std_logic;
            din :in     std_logic;
            dout    :out    std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
            ready   :out    std_logic
            );

    end component LFSR;


    signal  input_temp  :std_logic_vector(Nbit-1 downto 0);
    signal  input_LFSR  :std_logic;
    signal  output_LFSR :std_logic_vector(poly-1 downto 0);
    signal  ready_LFSR  :std_logic;
    constant crc_check  :std_logic_vector(poly-1 downto 0):= (others => '0');


    begin
        LFSR_o: LFSR    generic map (N => poly)

                port map(
                    clk     => clk,
                    reset   => reset,
                    din => input_LFSR,
                    dout    => output_LFSR,
                    ready   => ready_LFSR
                    );

    process (clk)
    variable i : natural := 0;
    begin
        if (md = '1') then
            input_temp(Nbit-1 downto poly)<=input(Nbit-1 downto poly);
            input_temp(7 downto 0) <=(others =>'0');

            if(rising_edge(clk)) then
                input_LFSR <= input_temp(i);
                i:= i+1;
                if(ready_LFSR = '1') then
                    dout_s <= input(Nbit-1 downto 0) & output_LFSR;
                end if;
            end if;

        elsif(md = '0') then
            input_temp(Nbit-1 downto 0)<=input(Nbit-1 downto 0);

            if(rising_edge(clk)) then
                input_LFSR <= input_temp(i);
                i:= i+1;
                if(ready_LFSR = '1') then
                    --codice per il controllo
                        for t in 0 to poly-1 loop
                            if (output_LFSR(t)='1') then
                                dout_r <=(others =>'0');
                                exit;
                            elsif(t=poly-1 and output_LFSR(t)='0') then
                                dout_r <= input(Nbit-1 downto poly);
                            end if;
                        end loop;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end rtl;
```

here the LFSR

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity LFSR is
    generic (NBit   : positive := 8);
    port(
        clk :in     std_logic;
        reset   :in     std_logic;
        din :in     std_logic;
        dout    :out    std_logic_vector(Nbit-1 downto 0);
        ready   :out    std_logic
        );
    end LFSR;
architecture rtl of LFSR is

    component DFC
        port(
            clk :in std_logic;
            reset   :in std_logic;
            d   :in std_logic;
            crc :out    std_logic;
            q   :out    std_logic
        );  
    end component DFC;

    signal q_s  : std_logic_vector (NBit-1 downto 0):= (others => '0');
    signal crc_t    : std_logic_vector (NBit-1 downto 0):= (others => '0'); --registro temporaneo su cui fare le operazioni

    signal int_0    :std_logic := '0';
    signal int_2    :std_logic := '0';
    signal int_4    :std_logic := '0';
    signal int_8    :std_logic := '0';




    begin 
        int_0<= din xor q_s(7);
        int_2<= q_s(1) xor q_s(7);
        int_4<= q_s(3) xor q_s(7);

        GEN: for i in 0 to Nbit-1 generate

            FIRST:  if i=0 generate
                    FF1: DFC port map (
                            clk     => clk,
                            reset   => reset,
                            d   => int_0,
                            crc => crc_t(i), --funziona benissimo se metto dout(i)
                            q   => q_s(i)
                            );

                end generate FIRST; 

            THIRD: if i=2 generate
                    FF2: DFC port map (
                            clk     => clk,
                            reset   => reset,
                            d   => int_2,
                            crc => crc_t(i),
                            q   => q_s(i)
                                );
                end generate THIRD;

            FIFTH: if i=4 generate
                    FF4: DFC port map (
                            clk     => clk,
                            reset   => reset,
                            d   => int_4,
                            crc => crc_t(i),
                            q   => q_s(i)
                                );
                end generate FIFTH;


            INTERNAL: if i>0 and i<Nbit-1 and i/= 2 and i/=4 generate
                    FFI: DFC port map (
                            clk     => clk,
                            reset   => reset,
                            d   => q_s(i-1),
                            crc => crc_t(i),
                            q   => q_s(i)
                                );
                end generate INTERNAL;

            LAST:    if i=Nbit-1 generate
                    FFN: DFC port map (
                            clk     => clk,
                            reset   => reset,
                            d   => q_s(i-1),
                            crc => crc_t(i),
                            q   => q_s(i)
                            );
                end generate LAST;
    end generate GEN;


    process(clk)
    variable t : natural := 0;
    begin
        --ready <= '0';
        if(rising_edge(clk)) then
            t:= t+1;
            if t=24 then --per qualche ragione ho bisogno di 3 cicli di clock in più per arrivare al risultato ricercato
                dout <= crc_t;
                ready <='1';
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end rtl;
```

here the DFF

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity DFC is 
    port(
        clk :in std_logic;
        reset   :in std_logic;
        d   :in std_logic;
        crc :out    std_logic;
        q   :out    std_logic
    );  
end DFC;

architecture rtl of DFC is
    begin
        process(clk, reset, d)
        begin
            if(reset = '1')then
                q <= '0';
                crc<= '0';
            elsif (clk'event and clk='1') then
                q <= d;
                crc <= d;
            end if;
        end process;
end rtl;
```

and finally here the testbench for the CRC

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity CRC_tb is
end CRC_tb;

architecture testbench of CRC_tb is

    component CRC is
        generic (
            NBit    : positive := 20; --da rimettere a 64
            poly    : positive := 8
            );
        port(
            clk :in     std_logic;
            reset   :in     std_logic;
            md  :in std_logic; --1 per sender, 0 per receiver
            input   :in     std_logic_vector(Nbit-1 downto 0);
            dout_s  :out    std_logic_vector(Nbit-1 downto 0);
            dout_r  :out    std_logic_vector(Nbit-poly-1 downto 0)
            );
    end component;

    constant T_CLK      :time       := 25 ns;
    constant T_sim      :time       := 2000 ns;
    signal sim_time     :std_logic  :='1';

    constant M      :integer    :=20; --da rimettere a 64, Nbit
    constant N      :integer    :=8; -- poly

    signal clk_tb       :std_logic  :='0';
    signal reset_tb     :std_logic  :='1';
    signal md_tb        :std_logic;
    signal input_tb     :std_logic_vector(M-1 downto 0);
    signal dout_s_tb    :std_logic_vector(M-1 downto 0);
    signal dout_r_tb    :std_logic_vector(M-N-1 downto 0);

    begin
        clk_tb      <= (not(clk_tb)and sim_time) after T_CLK/2;
        sim_time    <= '0' after T_sim;

        DUT_i : CRC
            generic map (
                Nbit => M,
                poly => N
                )
            port map (
                clk     => clk_tb,
                reset   => reset_tb,
                md  => md_tb,
                input   => input_tb,
                dout_s  => dout_s_tb,
                dout_r  => dout_r_tb
                ); 

        input_process : process(clk_tb)
            begin
                if(rising_edge(clk_tb)) then
                    md_tb <= '1';
                    input_tb <= "10100111010000000000";
                end if;
            end process input_process;
end testbench;
```

I was expecting that everything went fine given that the CRC code doesn't do much if not creating connections. I'm very new to VHDL so I can't understand very well what

> ** Error: (vsim-3733) C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/CRC2.0/CRC.vhd(50):
>   No default binding for component instance 'LFSR_o'.
>
> The following component generic is not on the entity: N Time: 0 ns 
>   Iteration: 0  Instance: /crc_tb/DUT_i/LFSR_o File:
>   C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/CRC2.0/LFSR.vhd
>
> Loading work.dfc(rtl)
>
> Error loading design

means.

Thanks all for the answers.

Comment: In some places you call the generic `N` and in other places `NBit`.

Comment: Where? I thought I was consistent in using N when referred to the LFSR in the CRC code

Comment: Component has a generic N, but the LFSR entity has generic called NBit (not N)

Comment: Ok, I thought I could name generic and port different when defining a component in an entity. Thanks

Comment: See IEEE Std 1076-2008 Annex I "**binding**: The process of associating a design entity and, optionally, an architecture with an instance of a component. A binding can be specified in an explicit or a default binding indication. (3.4, 7.3.2, 7.3.3, 14.4.3.3, 14.5.4)" where the numbers are subclauses. The error is defined in 7.3.3. There's only ever been one accepted answer mentioning 'binding indication' in a related question here, it's complicated. The error occurs during elaboration of CRC. You could change the name of generic N to NBit using explicit binding. It's easier to have them match.